# syntax error, unexpexted IF

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL
Why does it always say "syntax error, unexpexted IF"?

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE table SET col3=col3+1 WHERE conditions;

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
INSERT table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ('1', 2, 3, '4');

COMMIT
```

Comment: Do you execute that in a trigger or procedure?

Comment: I don't know that much MySQL so I don't know

Comment: Regardless, seems a good candidate for replacement with an `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY...`.

Comment: Insert "into" table......and that IF should be inside a routine....like an Stored Procedure.

Comment: Trying INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY right now

Comment: Thank you for the fast help
the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY way worked perfectly

Comment: @1c0re If this solved your issue, please post yourself an answer explaining the solution and accept it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer